# Approximating the mathematical expectation of the argmax of a Gaussian random vector

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, extreme-value

Let $X = \left( {{X_1},...,{X_n}} \right) \sim \mathcal{N}\left( {{\mathbf{\mu }},{\mathbf{\Sigma }}} \right)$  be a Gaussian random vector and $I = \mathop {\arg \max }\limits_{i = 1,n} {X_i}$.

$I$ has probability mass function

$\mathbb{P}\left( {I = i} \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {{X_i} = \mathop {\max {X_j}}\limits_{j = 1,n} } \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {{X_i} - \mathop {\max {X_j}}\limits_{j \ne i}  > 0} \right)$

and mathematical expectation

$\mathbb{E}I = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {i\mathbb{P}\left( {I = i} \right)} $

Generally speaking, for large $n$  and arbitrary covariance matrix ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$ , computing $\mathbb{E}I$ is very difficult because it requires the numerical evaluation of high-dimensional normal orthant integrals. So, apart from the IID and INID cases with a diagonal covariance matrix ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$, banded covariance matrices and degenerate cases such as ${\mu _j} \gg {\mu _{i \ne j}}$ , under which conditions on ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$   (e.g. correlation decay) can we get simple, easy-to-evaluate numerical approximations to  $\mathbb{E}I$ (and $\mathbb{V}I$  as well)?

The covariance matrices  ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$ I'm interested in look like this:

[image: Covariance matrix]

Until now, I’ve not been able to find anything about this problem.

Related questions:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153039/maximal-component-of-a-multivariate-gaussian-distribution
[Expectation of the softmax transform for Gaussian multivariate variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321947/expectation-of-the-softmax-transform-for-gaussian-multivariate-variables)

Comment: By "argmax" are you referring to what we call the "maximum order statistic" if we view the random vector as a sample, or to something else?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes the argmax is the maximum order statistic also noted ${X_{(n)}}$ in extreme value theory

Comment: It is not at all certain that we know of conditions that will allow for "easy numerical approximations" of the $n$-dimensional normal integral with correlation.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos ...Hence my question. For instance, I know from some papers in extreme value theory that if the correlations/covariances decay sufficiently fast, we can get simplified formulae for the maximum ${X_{(n)}}$. Therefore, we might get simplified formulae for the argmax as well, but I've not been able to find a single paper about this problem. Besides, sorry, ${X_{(n)}}$ is the maximum, not the argmax which is the index of the maximum.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Another favorable case, but not mine, is when ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$ is banded. In thise case the $n-$dimensional integrals can be reduced to integrals of dimension equal to the bandwidth.

Comment: @Alecos The maximum is a continuous random variable. Unless we’re talking about the maximum’s index, we don’t want to be looking at a pmf.

Comment: @Taylor I'm talking about the maximum index = the argmax, isn't it?

Comment: @FabricePautot yeah so not the max order statistic. You can simulate this for known mean and covariance matrix pairs. Have you tried that?

Comment: @FabricePautot have you made any progress on this problem?

Comment: @UthsavChitra Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the law of large numbers to approximate your expectation pretty easily.

Edit: Analyticaly you can multiply a bunch of normal cdf evaluations together. For $i > 0$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left( {I = i} \right) &= \mathbb{P}\left( {{X_i} = \mathop {\max {X_j}}\limits_{j = 1,n} } \right) \\
&= \prod_{j \ne i} \mathbb{P}\left( {{X_i} > X_j } \right) \\
&= \prod_{j \ne i} \mathbb{P}\left( Y_j \le 0  \right)
\end{align*}

where $Y_j \sim \text{Normal}(\mu_j - \mu_i, \Sigma_j + \Sigma_i)$.

If we code $i=0$ as the event that no data point is clearly a maximum, then $\mathbb{P}\left( I = 0 \right) = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left( I = k \right)$

Comment: Yes, sampling from $X$ is the easy way. But what if $n=81$ (as above), $n=1000$ or $n=100000$ (my own $n$'s are virtually unbounded)? Can we efficiently sample (e.g. in polynomial time) an arbitrary large multivariate normal distribution (I should know, but I don't) and how many samples do we need in order to properly estimate  $\mathbb{E}I$? If there is an efficient Monte Carlo method for arbitrary $n$ and ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$ then the problem is solved. Otherwise, we'd like to get efficient, analytic  approximations depending on the particular structure of ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$

Comment: Both of those sound like separate questions. If you want to simulate quickly for higher dimensional data, you might have to write more bespoke code and introduce parallelization. Required sample size calculations can be done using the CLT. I can add that in to the answer shortly if you’re interested.

Comment: ...sure I am. As stated in the question (and other related questions such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326320/numerical-evaluation-approximation-of-non-central-high-order-moments-of-high-dim, I'm considering the asymptotic case. Is there a polynomial time Monte Carlo algo for arbitary ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$?  If not, is there a polytime algo is some special cases? I'll add this in the question if you don't mind

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my question arises from a specific problem where $n$ is given by $n = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^d {{n_k}} $ where the ${{n_k}}$'s are positive integers and $d$ is the problem dimension. In practice, $d$ can be up to, say, 30, so that $n$ can be extremely large (typically ${n_k} \sim 100$). That's why  I'm looking for analytic approximation formulae rather than MC but for the time being that's the best we can do for small values of $d$

Comment: @FabricePautot *"How many samples do we need in order to properly estimate $\mathbb{E}(I)$?"* We could say that the sample distribution (for the mean of a sample from $I$) can be well approximated by a normal distribution. The standard deviation of the sample distribution will depend on the standard deviation of the distribution of $I$. This standard deviation will be in the worst case equal to $0.5 \cdot n$ (when the distribution of $I$ concentrates on the ends $P(I=1)=(I=n)=0.5$). You can use this to compute the desired necessary sample size for the Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Sorry, I can't follow you. This problem pertains to extreme value theory. For instance, if ${\mathbf{\Sigma }} = {{\mathbf{I}}_n}$ then by the Fisher-Tippet-Gnedenko theorem, the maximum follows a generalized extreme value distribution, asymptotically in the sample size, which is not a Gaussian distribution. For this reason, the argmax is basically not expected to follow a Gaussian distribution asymptotically as well, especially when ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$ has strong correlation structure.

Comment: @FabricePautot Yes, the distribution of the maximum does not follow a Gaussian distribution. However, the **mean of a sample from that distribution** does asymptotically approach a Gaussian distribution which will become more narrow as we increase the sample size.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Any proof of this please?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings On a daily basis I'm working in dimension $d \simeq 10$ with ${n_k} \simeq 100$, so that $n \simeq {10^{20}}$. Hence, given my modest computational means, MC methods aren't very practical. That's the reason why, as stated above, I'm rather looking for analytic results, e.g. bounds on $I$ depending on the correlation decay of ${\mathbf{\Sigma }}$. I've found a couple of papers but nothing really useful. As of today, I don't have anything better than taking the argmax of $\mathbb{E}X$. Generally speaking, this is a very difficult problem due to the very bad orthant integrals.

Comment: The meaning of $d$ and $n_k$ are not well explained in this question. What is the underlying *original* question/problem? Does the distinction between $d$, $n_k$ vs just $n$ matter? What intuition could we gain from it? Possibly there might be some simplification for specific types of $\Sigma$ but without further specification (of your daily situation) this question might be too broad. Even if there would be, in some utopian world, a solution to the difficult (broad/general) problem, then it might be still better to specify the situation more precisely in order to get more efficient results.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Only $n$ matters at the end. That's the problem: which conditions on the very, very large, covariance matrix, allow us to get bounds on $I$?  I gave some basic examples for which such bounds are available: diagonal covariance matrices, banded matrices and banded inverse covariance matrices. But my own matrices are more complex (not banded) and their correlation structure is not easy to describe even if there is a clear correlation decay. That's why I was looking for more general theorems for more general matrices.